# How to retrieve the LoaderExceptions property?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I get a error message while updating my service reference:

*Custom tool warning: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.*

How can I retrieve the LoaderExceptions property?

**Update:** My errors went away when I reimported the domain object projects. I have no idea why this fixed the issue, but I'm happy it's working.

Comment: How did you manage to fix this? What do you mean by "reimporting domain object project"? (remove reference to the project and re-add it again?)

Answer (score 162, accepted):

```
try
{
  // load the assembly or type
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  if (ex is System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException)
  {
    var typeLoadException = ex as ReflectionTypeLoadException;
    var loaderExceptions  = typeLoadException.LoaderExceptions;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not known to write fault free code, so there might be problems in the service. However when I generate code with the svcutil I get code that seems correct with my types reused (witch is my main issue actually)

Comment: I marked you as answer because I think it will be most helpful for others experiencing this warning/error.

Comment: I'm trying to use this solution, but I have no entry point in my WCF service around which to actually wrap a try block.

Comment: @Jordan Send me (some of) the code in a PM and I'll have a look

Comment: @KBoek, nevermind. I figured out the issue. It was a configuration problem with my end points.

Comment: This answer would work for me if it had anything to do with my code. I've placed a `try...catch` around my entire `Installer.cs` class, and nothing! My code does not throw this when it runs, only when I try to execute the Installer. Does anyone know **How to Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information?** Like, browse to a folder and view a log file?

Comment: The catch clause will catch all exceptions but only handle ReflectionTypeLoadExceptions. Something like this would be better.
`catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException ex)
{
    var typeLoadException = ex as ReflectionTypeLoadException;
    var loaderExceptions  = typeLoadException.LoaderExceptions;
}`

Comment: @ScottMunro: If you're catching it as one type, why create another variable with the same type and do a cast?  This should suffice: `catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException ex) { var loaderExceptions = ex.LoaderExceptions; }`.  Also, unless you expect the cast to fail and will check for null, it's better to do a direct cast so it will fail immediately and not later with a null reference exception: `var typeLoadException = (ReflectionTypeLoadException)ex;`

Comment: @NelsonRothermel My point was that it would be better to catch a specific exception rather than Exception. I did not need to change any of the code inside the conditional to make this point but your code is obviously an improvement.

Comment: @ScottMunro Fair enough.  :)

Comment: It doesn't even run for christ sakes. "var" undefined. Removed the var, and set the $ before the variables. Still doesn't save anything to the variables.

Comment: @Owl, putting $ in front of the variables is so PHP ... And "var" is supported  since .NET 3.0, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var

Comment: KBoek: Well i actually like $ variables - as a perl / bash programmer, not sure why I couldn't get this working, I suspect as you mentioned wrong version of .net...

Answer (score 84):

```
catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException ex)
{        
    foreach (var item in ex.LoaderExceptions)
    {
          MessageBox.Show(item.Message);                    
    }
}
```

I'm sorry for resurrecting an old thread, but wanted to post a different solution to pull the loader exception (Using the actual ReflectionTypeLoadException) for anybody else to come across this.

Comment: Just an FYI, if you're running a Win Service (like I am), MessageBox will not appear as UI elements are automatically blocked. Rest of implementation was helpful. Just saved to a log file instead. Thanks.

Comment: "The catch statement is missing its statement block". God, I hate powershell.

Comment: Many thanks, this solution is accurate as it pin points the exact problem. No point in catching the exception and do nothing.

Answer (score 11):

Using Quick Watch in Visual Studio you can access the LoaderExceptions from ViewDetails of the thrown exception like this:

```
($exception).LoaderExceptions
```

Comment: Thanks! Makes me wonder why not include that information without the need to access `LoaderExceptions`, as it actually contains relevant information.

Comment: Not all Exceptions have the LoaderExceptions property. Make sure you are casting or catching an exception of the appropriate type.

Answer (score 2):

Another Alternative for those who are probing around and/or in interactive mode:

> $Error[0].Exception.LoaderExceptions

Note: **[0] grabs the most recent Error from the stack**