# MVC Application - Retrieve the LoaderExceptions from Global.asax.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting the following error when trying to implement code from my peers:

Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

I see there is a posting for how to "How to retrieve the LoaderException property?" here ([How to retrieve the LoaderException property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667078/how-to-retrieve-the-loaderexception-property))

But, I do not understand where this try catch should go since the code to implement my peers code is in the Global.asax.cs file. (see below)

Any help would be appreciated and if you DOWN VOTE me, please explain why.

```
namespace IMS_STS_Example_SIT
{
 // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
 // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

 public class MvcApplication : StsMvcHttpApplication
 {
    protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        base.OnApplicationStarted();

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    }
 }
}
```

Here is the full error message from the UI:

[ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.]
   MyCompNameIT.Common.Utils.Installer.ConfigInstaller.Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store) in C:\MyCompNameProjects\PrideLands\Common\Main\Source\MyCompNameIT.Common\MyCompNameIT.Common.Utils\Installer\ConfigInstaller.cs:80
   Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Install(IWindsorInstaller[] installers, DefaultComponentInstaller scope) +200
   Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Install(IWindsorInstaller[] installers) +144
   MyCompNameIT.Common.Utils.InstallerExtension.WithMyCompNameDefaults(IWindsorContainer container) in C:\MyCompNameProjects\PrideLands\Common\Main\Source\MyCompNameIT.Common\MyCompNameIT.Common.Utils\InstallerExtension.cs:52
   MyCompNameIT.Common.Web.InstallerExtension.WithMyCompNameWebMvc(IWindsorContainer container) in C:\MyCompNameProjects\PrideLands\Common\Main\Source\MyCompNameIT.Common\MyCompNameIT.Common.Web\InstallerExtension.cs:20
   MyCompNameIT.Common.Web.MvcHttpApplication..cctor() in C:\MyCompNameProjects\PrideLands\Common\Main\Source\MyCompNameIT.Common\MyCompNameIT.Common.Web\IocHttpApplication.cs:30

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MyCompNameIT.Common.Web.MvcHttpApplication' threw an exception.]
   MyCompNameIT.Common.Web.MvcHttpApplication..ctor() +0
   IMS_STS_Example_SIT.MvcApplication..ctor() +40
   ASP.global_asax..ctor() in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ims_sts_example_sit\2c6588da\447046b5\App_global.asax.lkasnsc6.0.cs:0

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +159
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +256
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +127
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +14429965
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +200
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture) +28
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.CreateNonPublicInstance(Type type, Object[] args) +83
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +312
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +475

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12881108
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12722297

Comment: did you try the default super class of MVC instead of "StsMvcHttpApplication"

Comment: No. The StsMvcHttpApplication is where my peers code is. I will post the rest of the error message I am getting from the UI.

Comment: so you need to make sure all the depedencies of this class are there

Comment: Any ideas on how to find the missing classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `StsMvcHttpApplication` by `MvcHttpApplication` or make sure you are refering to StsMvcHttpApplication assemblies and all their dependencies

Comment: The StsMvcHttpApplication is where my peers code is. I posted the rest of the error message I am getting from the UI.