# How to get the LoaderExceptions in Matlab

Tags: .net, matlab, exception, assemblies

I am trying to load an assembly in Matlab using:

```
NET.addAssembly(libpath);
```

I get an exception with the **message**:

> Message: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve
>   the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

For this Exception **Identifier**:

> MATLAB:NET:CLRException:AddAssembly

**How can I access/get the LoaderExceptions in Matlab? Is it possible?** 
In C# you can do it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4667152/752842).

Answer (score 2):

The following code works for me:

```
try
  NET.addAssembly(assembly)
catch ex
end

ex.ExceptionObject.LoaderExceptions.Get(0).Message
```