# How can I retrieve the LoaderExceptions property from the Exception class?

Tags: c#, exception

I have a try catch method which would catch any exceptions that are thrown.

Something hasn't gone as planned and has thrown an exception. This is caught in the catch where it is thrown.

The error message I'm getting is:

> Unable to initialise application: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

I have tried finding the LoaderExceptions by selecting "View Detail" on the exception tool-tip when the exception is thrown. I also looked inside of the InnerException to see if it was there instead. I have also tried navigating to it using the Intermediate Window. However, when I do this I get the error of:

> error CS1061: 'Exception' does not contain a definition for 'LoaderException' and no extension method 'LoaderException' accepting a first argument of type 'Exception' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I also have tried using the [selected answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4667152/5191455), but this also didn't work. It fails the if condition and doesn't execute the code inisde.

The try catch looks something like this:

```
try
{
    // Code would go here...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex is System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException)
    {
        var typeLoadException = ex as System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException;
        var loaderExceptions = typeLoadException.LoaderExceptions;
    }

    throw new Exception("Unable to complete task: " + ex.Message, ex)
}
```

Unfortunately I am unable to find where the exception itself is thrown, it is a private NuGet package which I don't have access to the source code at the moment.

Obviously I am doing something wrong, any help would be appreciated to help me solve my issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I notice in your error it says "does not contain a definition for 'LoaderException'. Are you simply missing the 's' off the end, by any chance?

Comment: As the answer you linked to shows, you have to cast the exception - `ex as ReflectionTypeLoadException` or change the catch statement to `catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException ex)`

Comment: You linked an answer and then show the code, which is absolutely different, and then you are asking "why it doesn't work". Well.. how about trying to use exact code from the answer?

Comment: @Sinatr Like I said, I tried it and it didn't work. I didn't include it in the code simply for simplicity. I've updated the question now.

Comment: What you were asking in the title is exact duplicate. However, it seems you have another issue, related to that nuget you have mentioned. I'd recommend you to delete this question and ask instead another one, where you provide all related information: the code which you use now to catch exception, the **exact** error message (namely stack trace), all related info which may be important (target framework, platform, etc.). Try to create a new solution, install that nuget and reproduce the issue, then post [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Said above will only works if someone else is willing to debug for you. What "private NuGet" means? Does it has a name? Don't forget to mention it. You see, *someone* has to look into sources to localize the problem. If none can look... you got the idea.