# Error message pop up in Azure Functions interface

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

Getting following error message when selecting function in Azure Functions interface:

> Function ($HttpTrigger) Error: Unable to load one or more of the
>   requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more
>   information. Session Id: 1e96785112fc4979a19cb22b4eb40d99 Timestamp:
>   2017-12-09T23:07:55.666Z

[image]

Comment: May be you can check the logs by following "Monitor log files from a command line" mentioned in the docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring

Comment: Application Insights is turne on and there is nothing of value there. It doesn't even pickup this error

Comment: Application insights might not be getting initialized in this case. Have you attempted to view log files without AppInsights? This article:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#monitoring-without-application-insights, the section at the bottom labelled "Monitor log files from a command line"

Comment: I'm getting the same error message on a local machine. I'm using .net core azure function and the type it's complaining about is dbcontext from ef core

Comment: Are you using .net core 2.0 with Sdk.Functions 1.0.7 by any chance?

Answer (score -1):

Are you able to Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property?
Try following [How to retrieve the LoaderException property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667078/how-to-retrieve-the-loaderexception-property)

Comment: this is not working, since there is no place where you can make that try-catch block globally for Azure Functions.