# TypeLite -> TypeScript -> ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types

Tags: c#, visual-studio, typescript, t4

I get the following error when I try to use `Run Custom Tool` or `Debug T4 Template` from `TypeLite.Net4.tt`

> ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the
>   requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more
>   information.

If I then try to build the project after I get this error:

> Could not copy "obj\Debug\Shared.Web.dll" to
>   "bin\Debug\Shared.Web.dll". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed. The
>   file is locked by: "T4VSHostProcess.exe (9848)"

TypeLite has worked before but for some reason it has stopped working now. TypeLite is generating files from two projects, `Models` is a referenced project to `Shared.Web`. Both these DLLs are present in `bin\Debug\`.

I read an answer here on SO about retrieving the LoaderException and getting more information but I don't know how to do this for T4.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8824250/3850405

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4667152/3850405

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by editing `TypeLite.Net4.tt` and include the other assembly explicitly. This has worked before so I can't answer why I have to do this now.

```
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)Model.dll" #>
```