# Azure table: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I have an error saying 'Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information' showing inside Func.exe command prompt.

I found out when I comment all the codes except the one with Table Entity subclass. That is the code give me an exception.

```
public class RollCallHistoryEntity : TableEntity
{
    public RollCallHistoryEntity() { }

    public RollCallHistoryEntity(RollCallTransaction transaction)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = Convert.ToString(transaction.OrgId);
        this.RowKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        this.OrgId = transaction.OrgId;
        this.AttendanceId = transaction.AttendanceId;
        this.ActionId = transaction.ActionId;
        this.HappenedOn = transaction.HappenedOn;
```

[image]

```
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task Run([QueueTrigger("queue-trigger", Connection = "tuxdev_STORAGE")]string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");

        var queueItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RollCallTransaction>(myQueueItem);
        //var historyTable = await Azure.AzureTable.GetTable(Azure.AzureTable.TABLE_ROLLCALL_HISTORY);
        //var historyEntity = new Azure.Entity.RollCallHistoryEntity(queueItem);
    }
}
```

Don't worry about the RollCallProcessor, it was my old project. I recreate a new project with above code but still have the same problem.

Comment: If you could provide code about RollCallProcessor , it would be more helpful. This is a similar [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091853/error-message-unable-to-load-one-or-more-of-the-requested-types-retrieve-the-l), it seems that the issue is about .NET Framework version.

Comment: Is there a way to look at the LoaderException stacktrace.

Comment: Maybe you could catch the exception to get more information.

Comment: For me this exception occurred when I took a dependency on an x64 project. I couldn't find a way to actually read the LoaderExceptions property, but the solution was by running the functions in an x64 host, using this post: https://www.henkboelman.com/azure-function-x64-dev-setup/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to look at the LoaderException stacktrace.

You could use [StackTrace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx) class to  trace exception in your project.

Or you could retrieve [ReflectionTypeLoadException.LoaderException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.reflectiontypeloadexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to get more  information about LoaderException.

Catch the exception in [Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667078/how-to-retrieve-the-loaderexception-property):

```
try
{
  // load the assembly or type
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  if (ex is System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException)
  {
    var typeLoadException = ex as ReflectionTypeLoadException;
    var loaderExceptions  = typeLoadException.LoaderExceptions;
  }
}
```

> At the moment, Under Property of the Project, Application -> Target Framework is running in .netStandard 2.0

Just some features in trigger types  could use in **Azure function v2 preview** template:

[image]

For example, the BlobTrigger supports fine in v2. You could have a try to operate azure storage.

Create Azure function v2 preview:

[image]

Create BlobTrigger:

[image]

The Code in BlobTrigger:

```
public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([BlobTrigger("helloworld/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name, TraceWriter log)
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
   "storage account connection string");
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("helloworld");
            CloudAppendBlob blob = container.GetAppendBlobReference("log2.txt");
            using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"D:\log.txt"))
            {
                blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
            }
            log.Info($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
        }

}
```

The result in BlobTrigger:

[image]

So you'd better to choose the compatible platform version. More details please refer this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local).

> Azure Functions runtime 2.0 is in preview, and currently not all features of Azure Functions are supported.

Comment: I don't know what is going on... At the moment, I tried to reference a Azure Table I received Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=8.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Could not find or load a specific file. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131621). But I did add a package with 8.6.0 WindowsAzure.Storage .

Comment: I have nugget package added .nET.sdk.Functions package 1.0.9 and Storage package. The .Net.SDK.Functiions is using Storage 8.6.0 instead of 9.1.0

Comment: One things strange if I install a nugget package of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage to 9.1.0, the error is the same. Or even uninstalled, there is no compile problem but function still run with the same error.

Comment: What about your.net framework version. Check the compatibility of dependencies in [Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions/) nuget packages. And it seems that the [WindowAzure.Storage](https://image.ibb.co/j3hyzc/wbjob1.png) has alerady in this package. You needn't add a seperate package again.

Comment: At the moment, Under Property of the Project, Application -> Target Framework is running in .netStandard 2.0

Comment: In this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions), you know  the 2.0 is the preview version. And this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local)."Azure Functions runtime 2.0 is in preview, and currently not all features of Azure Functions are supported. "

Comment: The [ConfigurationManager](https://image.ibb.co/fXFohx/azurefunction21.png) Exclamation mark. It shows the warning about .net standard 2.0.

Comment: And the similar issue about LoaderException is also mentioned the platform version. You'd better to choose the compatibility version  of  platform.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166928/discussion-between-janley-zhang-and-littlefunny).