# Exception-User Handled: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: 'Unable to load one or more of the requested types

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I developed a web application using AdminLTE MVC Template in visual studio 2017. I just added a new scaffolded items (MVC 5 Controller with views, using Entity Framework) of a folder.

And then, I get this error:-

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException' in mscorlib.dll
An exception of type 'System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
```

Do you know why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

**Answers**:
What I did was to remove/exclude some javascript syntax at the bottom of the Index page, and after that it works just fine.

Comment: Nobody never reads exception messages :( _"Unable to load one or more of the requested types."_ means that asp.net was trying to load some requested types, but failed. It also suppose you to [Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667078/how-to-retrieve-the-loaderexception-property).

Comment: I already read the comments and answers in that question, but still i dont understand any of it. They showed the coding they wrote but I dont know where to insert those codes??? I'm totally lost right now @vasily.sib

Comment: debug your code. When this exception will occure, VS will show you a dialog where you may found your exception details. Look over there for `LoaderExceptions` of your exception.