# Installing NuGet package causes server error in application (ASP.NET on .NET Framework)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, nuget, azure-application-insights, .net-framework-version

I have an ASP.NET web application targeting .NET Framework 4.6.2 (VB.NET, not C#). I'm running it locally with IIS.

When I installed Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 2.21.0 using NuGet and re-loaded the site locally, I received a server error:

`Server Error in '/' Application.  Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.`

Three considerations:

1. I didn't change any code- I *just* installed the package.
2. The dependency tree NuGet installed for `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` 2.21.0 in this project included:

```
System.Buffers.4.5.1
System.Numerics.Vectors.4.5.0
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.5.0.0
System.Memory.4.5.4
System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource 5.0.0
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.2.21.0
```

None of those pre-existed in my project, so I'm certain I only installed new packages which shouldn't conflict or crossover with any pre-existing dependencies.

3. There are no build errors when rebuilding the project. It only throws the above error on the web page.

I tried wiping the bin and obj folders, and restarting IIS. Didn't help.

I configured NuGet to restore packages and deleted all of the packages in the solution and rebuilt it. That didn't help, either.

The project has deprecated packages. However, they have nothing to do with AppInsights, and I'd like to avoid a re-write if possible.

Generally, it *seems* like there is a dependency conflict within one or more dependency tree(s) that reference one or more assemblies in the GAC, but I have no clear way of identifying the tree(s) or fixing it/them.

How can I diagnose which package/assembly is causing this error if none of the new packages was referenced by any existing one?

Comment: *"Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information"*. You haven't provided the additional information that you found when you did that, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I'd had trouble finding the LoaderExceptions property, but I just realized my mistake. My code was loading assemblies with SimpleInjector, which was throwing an exception of type "Exception" rather than "ReflectionTypeLoadException". Catching the exception and viewing it's inner exception revealed that System.Net.HTTP Version 4.1.1.3 was failing to load. I changed that package version and re-ran the application, and it failed, giving an error which seems related to SimpleInjector: "Server Error in '/' Application. Type IRequestHandler<SomeClass, OtherClass> has already been registered".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Server Error in '/' Application. Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

As you mentioned, the error could be due to the compatibility or conflicts between the error and also there must be some issues with the application code.

- Try upgrading the existing package versions to be compatible with the Application Insights package version.
- To know the exact error, check **LoaderExceptions** property or handle the exceptions with try, catch block in your application.
- Refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667078/how-to-retrieve-the-loaderexception-property) to handle the LoaderExceptions.

---

Try configuring Application Insights Manually, refer [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net#add-application-insights-automatically):

- Right click on the `project=>configure Application Insights`:

[image]

- Select `Application Insights sdk`=>`Next=>Finish=>Close`.
- Add your Application Insights connection string in `ApplicationInsights.config` before the closing tag .

```html
    <ConnectionString>your_application_insights_connection_string</ConnectionString>    
</ApplicationInsights>
```

---

I tried installing the **Application insights** package version `2.21.0` in my .NET web application version 4.8 (vb.net).
I could run the application without any issues:

**References of my project:**

[image]

Comment: The link you shared to get the LoaderExceptions initially misled me, since my code was loading assemblies with SimpleInjector, which was throwing an exception of type "Exception" rather than "ReflectionTypeLoadException". Catching the exception and viewing it's inner exception revealed that System.Net.HTTP Version 4.1.1.3 was failing to load. I changed that package version and re-ran the application, and it failed, giving an error which seems related to SimpleInjector: "Server Error in '/' Application.
Type IRequestHandler<SomeClass, OtherClass> has already been registered".